# Tkinter after() fails when system time is changed

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tkinter, time, raspberry-pi3

Is there a way to cancel and reschedule tkinter after() events when the system time is updated, or preemptively update the after() scheduler?

### Description

I have a custom GUI created in tkinter using Python3.7 on Raspbian (fork of Debian-Linux for Raspberri Pi). I created a screen to adjust the system time.

If the date & time are set to the future, everything is OK, but if it's set to the past, anything using the tkinter after() method to schedule events never happens. I believe after() works by polling system time, and the scheduled times are now far in the future.

I verified this by setting the time for a minute into the past. Initially, any elements using the after() function stopped updating, but the GUI was still responsive to click events. A minute later, those elements continued to update.

### Related

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066657/tkinter-after-that-survives-clock-rewinding) back in 2010 is about the same problem, but has no solutions.

---

Side Note - the user running the GUI doesn't have privileges to set the time, so it is actually starting a service (which it has the privilege to do), and writing a time string to a FIFO pipe. The service running as root reads the pipe and updates the time. I have verified the time is correctly set with this method.

### Update

I never came up with a good way for this to work. So I have a message box to say that application would need to restart after the time change so the user at least knew what was about to happen. If they were OK with that, the application terminated and relaunched itself.

Comment: I looked at how the `after` method is defined. Apparently someone already suggested it could use `time.sleep` instead of calling TCL command, thought it was never implemented. IMO to overwrite the method you will need to make a lot of changes, and it might be easier to just use threading to replace `after` instead for your case.

Comment: @HenryYik yes, I was thinking along the same lines. just didn't know if anyone had figured a good work around for it before I spend a bunch of time rewriting stuff.